# Thread should stop but it doesnt

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

So now I have this: hooked hotkeys and a `volatile bool` that is checking in a while loop.

```
UserActivityHook actHook;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actHook = new UserActivityHook();
    actHook.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(klawisze);
    actHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(klawisze2);
    actHook.Start();
}

public void pw()
{
    while (!stopIt)
    {
        SetCursorPos(576, 363);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        SetCursorPos(650, 363);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        SetCursorPos(650, 430);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }   
}
public void Stop()
{
    stopIt = true;
}
private volatile bool stopIt;

public void dw()
{
    while (!stopIt)
    {
        SetCursorPos(860, 350);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        SetCursorPos(890, 350);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        SetCursorPos(890, 380);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}

public void klawisze(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Thread w1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pw));
    Thread w2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(dw));

    try
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 21) //CTRL + SHIFT + U
        {       //1

            stopIt = false;
            w1.Start();
            if (e.KeyChar == 9)
            {
                Stop();
                w1.Join();
            }
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == 9) //CTRL + SHIFT + I
        {   //2

            stopIt = false;
            w2.Start();
            if (e.KeyChar == 21)
            {
                Stop();
                w2.Join();
            }
        }
    }
```

It's not closing first drawing and in effect when i press 1st hotkey and then second its drawing 2 triangles at same time.  What is wrong here?

Comment: hmm I don't see any loop ? could you post them as well?

Comment: This is awful code putting `Thread.Sleep` calls on the UI thread. What are you trying to do here? Maybe there's a better solution for you?

Comment: @Enigmativity I know its awful code... I want this: when i press 1st hotkey coursor will "write" one triangle frequently and when i press 2nd hotkey it will "write" other triangle in other place (when 1st hotkey press - "write" 1st trangle etc...)

Comment: Why does it need to repeatedly draw the triangle? And why have the delay between each line?

Comment: @Enigmativity It must repeeatedly draw with delays, any idea ?

Comment: Why must it "repeatedly draw with delays"?

Comment: It will be a program that draws triangles with delays...

Answer (score 0):

I hope that is the answer for your question. You should make another thread,or this will not work right. However i would send the boolean 'firstLoop' from the winform to your other thread. My solution is not 100% correct...

```
Boolean firstLoop = false;

if (e.KeyChar == 21) //CTRL + SHIFT + U
{
    firstLoop = true

    while (firstLoop == true)
    {        
          SetCursorPos(576, 363);
          Thread.Sleep(50);
          SetCursorPos(650, 363);
          Thread.Sleep(50);
          SetCursorPos(650, 430);
          Thread.Sleep(50);
     }
}
if (e.KeyChar == 9) //CTRL + SHIFT + I
{  
    firstLoop = false;

    while (firstLoop == false)
    {
       SetCursorPos(860, 350);
       Thread.Sleep(50);
       SetCursorPos(890, 350);
       Thread.Sleep(50);
       SetCursorPos(890, 380);
       Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, its not correct... what other thread u mean ? thx

Comment: If you use Thread.Sleep() the whole winform is 'locked'.To bypass that i would do the loops in another thread. just my idea

Comment: Iam busy right now. Here are some examples <br/>-[How to start with threads](http://www.csharp-examples.net/create-new-thread/)<br/> -[invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569482/c-sharp-threading-using-invoke-freezing-the-form)